# update object System.Printing.PrintQueue

Tags: .net, powershell

I need to update an attribute in a printer driver. I'm able to get the right information but i don't know how to change this value.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Printing

$adminServer = [System.Printing.PrintSystemDesiredAccess]::AdministrateServer
$adminPrinter = [System.Printing.PrintSystemDesiredAccess]::AdministratePrinter

$server = new-object System.Printing.LocalPrintServer $adminServer

$queues = $server.GetPrintQueues()

foreach($q in $queues){
$objPrinter = new-object System.Printing.PrintQueue -argumentList $server,$q.Name,$adminPrinter
$objPrinter.CurrentJobSettings.CurrentPrintTicket.PageMediaType
}
```

The output of `$objPrinter.CurrentJobSettings.CurrentPrintTicket.PageMediaType` is `Unknown` and should be changed to `AutoSelect`

Can someone help me? :)

Comment: Have you tried `$objPrinter.CurrentJobSettings.CurrentPrintTicket.PageMediaType = "AutoSelect"`?

Comment: This will only change the value of the variable `$objPrinter` but will not write back the value to the driver(settings).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while since I worked with Printer Management on Windows, but I'm fairly certain you want to update the `DefaultPrintTicket` rather than whatever settings are associated with the current job, so set it like this instead:

```
$objPrinter.DefaultPrintTicket.PageMediaType = 'AutoSelect'
```

... and then persist the configuration changes in the print server with `PrintQueue.Commit()`:

```
$objPrinter.Commit()
```